# Javascript is not working on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I've a multiple select on my code with the `onchange` function `ajax` call,when the value is passed through the ajax it gets data from database and plot the chart by `highcharts` script,my problem is `javascript` is not worrking on ajax call,please suggest anything best,thanks in advance

> source.php

```
 <script>
    function something(str)
    {

       if (str=="")
          {
         document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="";
          return;
          }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
           else
           {
             xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {

          document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

           }
          }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","destination.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     } </script>

<body>
 <select multiple="multiple" onchange="something(this.value);">
 <option>value1</option>
 ......
<option>valuen</option></select>

 <div id="div1"></div>
```

> destination.php

on here (destination page) get data from the database using the requested value from ajax

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
$var=$_REQUEST['str'];

$query=mysql_query("select * from table where column=$var");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {

   $value[]=$row['data'];
}

<script>
<!--- here my highcharts script for ploting graph by the above fetching value from database --!>
  </script>
 ?>
```

Comment: Do not mark questions with jQuery unless you want jQuery answers (which would be a fraction of the code size you have now).

Comment: What JavaScript error are you getting?

Comment: So please replicate it as live demo.

Comment: your ajax call code is working well, I made some tests. you can take a look in your browser debuging console you will see your ajax request

Comment: try to do test like something('hello');
if works for you then your problem is from your <select multiple/>

Comment: yeah,i checked with simple javascript alert like <script>alert('hai');</script>,but damm is not working with ajax call.